# How do I insert multiple rows into MySql using C# where columns have dates?

Tags: c#, datetime

The following class captures **SendQueue** objects from API `json` responses:

```
public class SendQueue
{
    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

}
```

When I receive the object, I convert the `SendDate` value to string to insert into a MySQL database, but the formatting apparently is not accepted by the DB and so the insert fails.

When I convert the value to string, the formatting of the SendDate is **"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"** whereas the database accepts **"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"**.

Of course, a better way of handling this is via parameterized queries. But since I am using batch inserts, I am unable to use DateTime objects.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

I will have the same problem if I [use Bulk Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883376/how-to-bulk-insert-into-mysql-using-c-sharp) as well since the dates will eventually be converted to strings stored in a file.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in the database?

Comment: 3. Neither, the correct place to format the DateTime value into a string *is when you need to display it*. The database should be able to accept DateTime *values*, not formatted as strings.

Comment: You can parse the Datetime when the request reaches the WEB API and before storing into the DB. This will give you more control since you can format it depending on which DB engine you will store it in. You can format it before sending it in the mobile or web application if you know what is the storage format accepted by the DB and you will never change it.

Comment: As you say, the correct place is via parameter queries, sending the dates as dates and letting the framework take care of it.  Is there a reason why you're not taking that approach?  If it's because you're not sure how, ask that question.  If there is some legitimate reason, include it in the question so we can give you a more informed answer; as currently both options are "wrong" given the information available.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm

Comment: @MatthewWatson I think it's misunderstood. I don't store dates in the database as strings. The database column type is `datetime`. The INSERT query I generate in my code is a string and not via the parameterized queries.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I think it's misunderstood. I don't store dates in the database as strings. The database column type is `datetime`. The INSERT query I generate in my code is a string and not via the parameterized queries.

Comment: @MatthewWatson plus, I am using batch inserts (`INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`) and I doubt if one can use parameterized queries when using batch INSERTS. But feel free to tell me I am wrong.

Comment: @JohnLBevan this does not work when you are using batch inserts. Parameterized queries are best when used for one statement. But I prepare my data so that I use them in a batch statement (e.g. `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`) I doubt if this works there.

Comment: Cool, so your real question is "How do I insert multiple rows into MySql using C# where columns have dates?".  For SQL Server I know you can insert a datatable as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405622/361842 - I've not tried with MySql, but will do some reading...

Comment: @JohnLBevan exactly. SQL Server is much simpler. And yes that is my question.

Comment: @JohnLBevan I changed the question title and edited the text so that it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, bulk adapter seems helpful, but only seems to work if you have data in a text file first.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html.  There's some comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25323560/most-efficient-way-to-insert-rows-into-mysql-database but all look hacky or don't use the single insert as you requested...  Maybe the best option is simply to loop through all rows inserting one by one?

Comment: If you have to write all at once for some reason (e.g. performance?), and the bulk loader doesn't help, the best option would be to write the logic to escape and format data in your data layer, so you can reuse it should you have other entities with the same need, and should MySql ever provide support for table type parameters you can easily switch over to the better solution.

Comment: @JohnLBevan but if bulk uploader eventually reads from a text file, we are again inserting data using string, am I not right? Won't we end up in the same situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183240/discussion-between-johnlbevan-and-disasterkid).

Answer (score 2):

You should use an appropriate [`DateTime` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) in your schema. Do not use strings to represent `Date`s or `DateTime`s or `Time`s, numbers, or anything else that is not a native string.

MySql allows for the following schema types:

```
DATE
TIME
DATETIME
TIMESTAMP
YEAR
```

In this case the most appropriate one would be `DATETIME`. This aligns with the .net type `System.DateTime`. If you are using ADO.NET then you should be using parameters in your queries. Example:

```
using(MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (sendDate) VALUES (@sendDate)"))
{
     m.Parameters.Add("@sendDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myObj.SendDate;
     // rest of code
}
```

### Batch Insert

You do not have to run one insert statement at a time. You can easily create one statement with multiple tuples that you want to insert. Here is sample c# code that does that with 1 column. You can easily extend this with multiple values per tuple.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO table (sendDate) VALUES (";
var parameters = input.Select((queue, i) => new MySqlParameter("@sendDate" + i.ToString(), MySqlDbType.DateTime)).ToArray();
sql += string.Join("), (", parameters.Select(_ => _.ParameterName)) + ")";
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
    parameters[i].Value = input[i].SendDate;
}

using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
  command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
  connection.Open();
  command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

---

### When to convert?

The code stack should always convert a `DateTime` to a `string` as late as possible up the call stack, generally in the Presentation Layer (at the point a Human has to read it). The reverse is also true, a `string` input should be converted to a `DateTime` as early as possible going down the call stack (so again, in the presentation layer).

---

### Why not varchar for Dates?

If you are wondering *why* you should not store `DateTime` as a `string` see this previous answer: [When to use VARCHAR and DATE/DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4759039/1260204). I'll quote the important stuff:

> Some of the disadvantages of the VARCHAR version:
>
> - You can't easily add / subtract days to the VARCHAR version.
> - It is harder to extract just month / year.
> - There is nothing stopping you putting non-date data in the VARCHAR column in the database.
> - The VARCHAR version is culture specific.
> - You can't easily sort the dates.
> - It is difficult to change the format if you want to later.
> - It is unconventional, which will make it harder for other developers to understand.
> - In many environments, using VARCHAR will use more storage space. This may not matter for small amounts of data, but in commercial environments with millions of rows of data this might well make a big difference.

---

### Time Zones and Values

Do not forget about time zones if this is applicable to your application. It is recommended to always store a `DateTime` UTC value in the database instead of a local timezone value. The UTC value can then be sent to the presentation layer where the presentation layer is responsible for applying the local time zone to the value (optional). Some UI frameworks have built in mechanisms for doing this in the `DateTime` controls. Again, the reverse is also true, have the presentation layer convert any input to a UTC `DateTime` value and send that back down the call stack to the server.

Comment: The reason I did not use parameterized queries was that I INSERT many records with a single script and I did not find a good library for bulk insert in MySQL.

Comment: Using single insert queries the type you so brilliantly described slows down the word when we have a couple hundred thousand rows. I either need to use bulk inserts which demand that the entire dataset is written to a .csv file first, but then I realized having one insert with many rows included is significantly faster than single inserts and that is why I adopted this method.

Comment: @Disasterkid - see the addition, heading `Batch Insert`. You can create batches that insert data in the same command. The sample code can be extended with additional values depending on the width of the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Per your updated question, it seems the root issue is that you need a way to insert multiple rows via a single insert statement.

Ideally you'd provide a stored procedure which could accept a table type as input, as could be done in the SqlServer world: [Insert entire DataTable into database at once instead of row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405373/insert-entire-datatable-into-database-at-once-instead-of-row-by-row/10405622#10405622)

Given that's not an option for MySQL at time of writing however, there are a few alternatives...

If you need to do this because you need all rows to be inserted in the same transaction, simply wrap your inserts in a transaction.  Code would be something like this (untested as I don't have MySQL).

```
public void InsertMySql(string connectionString, string command, DataTable data)
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    foreach (var row in data.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        foreach (var cell in data.Columns)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{cell.Name}", row[cell]);
                        }
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch 
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to do this for performance reasons, another option may be to look into a third party library such as: https://github.com/zzzprojects/Bulk-Operations.  I've not tried this personally, but the library looks promising / the publisher (zzzprojects) are quite well known and respected / maintain the popular site SQL Fiddle amongst other projects.

```
public static void InsertMySql(string connectionString, DataTable data)
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
        bulk.BulkInsert(data); //assumes your data table's table name, column names/definitions match your table's; I think.  See https://bulk-operations.net/bulk-insert for what documentation's available
    }
}
```

Comment: I can consider transactions. But is using multiple single parameterized INSERTs inside of one transaction _faster_ than running the same number of single parameterized INSERTs without that transaction? / Also is using transactions this way any faster than batch inserts?

Comment: I've not suggested the transaction approach for performance, but for the functional impact (i.e. if you insert 3 rows then others looking at the database will see no rows until the transaction's committed, then they'll see 3;whereas without a transaction if the rows are inserted one by one they may see 1 or two rows; which in some scenarios may be invalid (e.g. finance system where you're creating different rows for credits and debits, and require that they always have to balance).

Comment: Transactions can improve performance since some checks can be performed for all rows at once rather than for each individual insert; but they can impact performance by tying up resources / causing blocking.  If performance is your aim try experimenting with both approaches with realistic data and load to get an idea of the real life output.